# jquery countdown invalid date countdown

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-countdown

I'm using jquery.countdown to create a countdown but it seems it shows the wrong date when making the countdown. What I have:

```
<?php 
$timestamp = strtotime(GetConfig($link, 'coming_soon_date'));
$formatted_date =  date('Y/n/j H:i:s', $timestamp);
?>
```

GetConfig will get the date in string format (2020/7/1).

After that, I have the following code in my javascript:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var javascript_date = new Date("<?php echo $formatted_date; ?>");
    var releaseDate = javascript_date;



    $('#clockFlat').countdown(releaseDate).on('update.countdown', function(event) {
    var $this = $(this).html(event.strftime('<div class="clockCard px-1"> <span>%d</span> <br> <p class="bg-amber clockFormat lead px-1 black"> Day%!d </p> </div>'
        + '<div class="clockCard px-1"> <span>%H</span> <br> <p class="bg-amber clockFormat lead px-1 black"> Hour%!H </p> </div>'
        + '<div class="clockCard px-1"> <span>%M</span> <br> <p class="bg-amber clockFormat lead px-1 black"> Minute%!M </p> </div>'
        + '<div class="clockCard px-1"> <span>%S</span> <br> <p class="bg-amber clockFormat lead px-1 black"> Second%!S </p> </div>'))
    });


    });
</script>
```

It keeps telling me that's 1 day and 9 hours.
What I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Please click edit, click `[<>]` snippet editor and replace all PHP with HTML in a [mcve] - you also need to add the "strftime" from some library

Comment: Did you check the console for errors? Does countdown() is a Jquery function?

Comment: The countdown starts. But instead of showing me like 1 month and 12 days, just show me 1 day. I guess it's a date format I'm not doing right, but can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The countdown starts. But instead of showing me 1 month and 12 days, it just shows me 1 day.

The issue is that you have used `%d` for "days" - you need to use `%D` for number of days

From: http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/documentation.html

> %d    %-d Days left **(taking away weeks)**
>
> %D    %-D Total count of days till the end

so you would use `%d` in combination with `%w` (1 week 1 day) *or* `$D` without `%w` (8 days)

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks! I was missing that about days (%d vs %D)

Comment: @Tiago glad you got it working - easy enough to mix them and %d would be the obvious for days